# Easy painless backup of server?

Tags: server, backup

I've recently started playing around with ubuntu server, trying out everything I can imagine.  Along the way I've made some mistakes, poor choices and installed some crap that ill never need.

My plan, now that I half way know what I'm doing, is to start from scratch again, and only mess with the minimal settings/programs and have it as streamlined as it can be.

Once I'm done, I'd like to make a backup of everything except a giant data hdd that isn't part of the small install disk (installed on sda, data on sdb) so that in the case the file system hdd fails, I can swap it out and recover and move on.

What would be the most painless way to do this?
Also, if that did happen and I needed to recover, all I would need to do is remount the data hdd and it would work the same as before, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with a built-in back-up system but I've had really good results using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Clonezilla is a free and open-source utility that has the ability to create and restore image backups of your full hard-disk or partitions. It can be downloaded and run as a LiveCD which makes creating and restoring backups really easy - even when your OS is not functional, or completely missing - as would be the case when your hard-drive crashes.